# Node able to distribute the redis shards after maintanence in one node

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

In redis cluster
I have made maintenance mode on one node-1 using the command "rladmin node 1 maintenance_mode on"

After that I reverted the maintenance mode using the command "rladmin node 1 maintenance_mode off"

But still the node-1 is not able to get any shards assigned after maintenance off"

```
 CLUSTER NODES:
    NODE:ID  ROLE                      SHARDS  CORES       FREE_RAM     PROVISIONAL_RAM    VERSION   STATUS
    node:1   master                     0/0     80          5.2GB/8GB    0KB/0KB            6.2.8-64  OK
    *node:2  slave                     3/100   80          5.25GB/8GB   3.54GB/6.56GB      6.2.8-64  OK
    node:3   slave                     3/100   80          5.38GB/8GB   3.67GB/6.56GB      6.2.8-64  OK
```

Is there a way to recover this back. Currently our shards are distributed like this.
[image]